# Download link as response after sharing with Facebook feed dialog?

Tags: facebook, feed

I'm trying to use the following code so when a person clicks on a picture the dialog box comes up for them to share it on their news feed. When they press share a download box should appear as in 'save as/cancel' and so on. If they cancel before sharing it, a message should pop up saying that they need to share to be able to download.

I have got it to come up with the dialog when the image is pressed and everything works but i dont know how to put the rest into the code. I'm guessing it's to do with the response part at the bottom but i cant figure it out or find something on how to use it anywhere. I have tryed every possible google search I can think off at the moment.

Thanks in advance for any help!

(I don't have any of my info in the code and I just used the Facebook example for the most part)

```
  <body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'><img src="RANDOM IMAGE.png" alt="IMAGE"/></a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

        <script> 
          FB.init({appId: "1234567890", status: true, cookie: true});

          function postToFeed() {

            // calling the API ...
            var obj = {
              method: 'feed',
              link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
              picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
              name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
              caption: 'Reference Documentation',
              description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
            };

            function callback(response) {
              document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
            }`enter code here`

            FB.ui(obj, callback);
          }
        </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check response['post_id'] in "function callback". If user really share your picture, facebook send post id. Then you can call javascript function to appear save/cancel.

Comment: I think I know what you mean but I don't really know much about JavaScript. Could you please give me an example or point me in the right direction? Thanks for your help!